# Telerik Rad Grid change display format and interval for filter time picker

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

I have a grid column as follows in my WebForms application:

```
<telerik:GridDateTimeColumn CurrentFilterFunction="GreaterThanOrEqualTo" DataField="ClockedInAt" DataType="System.DateTime" EditDataFormatString="dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm" FilterControlAltText="Filter column column" FilterDateFormat="dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm" PickerType="DateTimePicker" UniqueName="column">
</telerik:GridDateTimeColumn>
```

I want to change the Time Picker displayed in the **filter bar** to:

1. Display time in 24 hour format viz HH:mm
2. Change the interval from 1 hour to 30 mins

How can I achieve this?